# IndexError: index is out of bounds for axis 0 with size

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, machine-learning

I have array `x_train` and `targets_train`. I want to shuffle the training data and split it into smaller batches and use the batches as training data. My original data has 1000 rows and each time I try to use 250 rows of them :

```
    x_train = np.memmap('/home/usr/train', dtype='float32', mode='r', shape=(1000, 1, 784))
# print(x_train)
targets_train = np.memmap('/home/usr/train_label', dtype='int32', mode='r', shape=(1000, 1))
train_idxs = [i for i in range(x_train.shape[0])]
np.random.shuffle(train_idxs)


num_batches_train = 4
def next_batch(start, train, labels, batch_size=250):
    newstart = start + batch_size
    if newstart > train.shape[0]:
        newstart = 0
    idxs = train_idxs[start:start + batch_size]
    # print(idxs)
    return train[idxs, :], labels[idxs, :], newstart


# x_train_lab = x_train[:200]
# # x_train = np.array(targets_train)
# targets_train_lab = targets_train[:200]
for i in range(num_batches_train):
    x_train, targets_train, newstart = next_batch(i*batch_size, x_train, targets_train, batch_size=250)
```

The problem is, when I shuffle the training data and try to access to batches I get error saying:

```
    return train[idxs, :], labels[idxs, :], newstart
    IndexError: index 250 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 250
```

Is there anybody who knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If size is 250, the last index is probably 249, as it starts from 0

Comment: Yes if I don't Shuffle the first batch indices might be from 0 to 249 but the next one would be 250 to 499 and so on .. If I shuffle the indices then the first batch might have index number 619! which I get error           "IndexError: index 652 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 250
"    ... I mean the problem is It doesn't understand to accept the rows and reset the indices!

Comment: Are there contents in the variables `x_train` and `targets_train` that you pass to the function? I'd print and make sure there're indeed 1000 shuffled rows.

Comment: The problem is how you iterate, and change `x_train` each time.  Indexing that works the first time fails on the 2nd.

Answer (score 3):

(edit - first guess about `newstart` deleted)

In this line:

```
x_train, targets_train, newstart = next_batch(i*batch_size, x_train, targets_train, batch_size=250)
```

you change the size of `x_train` with each iteration, yet you continue to use the `train_idxs` array that you created for the full size array.

It's one thing to pull out random values from `x_train` in batches, but you have to keep the selection arrays consistent.

========================

Reducing your code to a simple case

```
import numpy as np
x_train = np.arange(20).reshape(20,1)
train_idxs = np.arange(x_train.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(train_idxs)

num_batches_train = 4
batch_size=5
def next_batch(start, train):
    idxs = train_idxs[start:start + batch_size]
    print(train.shape, idxs)
    return train[idxs, :]

for i in range(num_batches_train):
    x_train = next_batch(i*batch_size, x_train)
    print(x_train)
```

a run produces:

```
1658:~/mypy$ python3 stack39919181.py 
(20, 1) [ 7 18  3  0  9]
[[ 7]
 [18]
 [ 3]
 [ 0]
 [ 9]]
(5, 1) [13  5  2 15  1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack39919181.py", line 14, in <module>
    x_train = next_batch(i*batch_size, x_train)
  File "stack39919181.py", line 11, in next_batch
    return train[idxs, :]
IndexError: index 13 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
```

I fed the (5,1) `x_train` back to the `next_batch` but tried to index it as though it were the original.

Changing the iteration to:

```
for i in range(num_batches_train):
    x_batch = next_batch(i*batch_size, x_train)
    print(x_batch)
```

lets it run through producing 4 batches of 5 rows.

Comment: interesting, what's the logic behind naming your program stack followed by the unique question number?

Comment: I've answered enough questions that this is the easiest way to keep the script names unique.  Though I rarely have reason to revist the scripts after a few days.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line in the function definition:

```
idxs = train_idxs[start:start + batch_size]
```

Change it to:

```
idxs = train_idxs[start: newstart]
```

Then it should work as expected!

Also, please change the variable names in the `for` loop to something like:

```
batch_size = 250
for i in range(num_batches_train):
    x_train_split, targets_train_split, newstart = next_batch(i*batch_size, 
                                                              x_train,
                                                              targets_train,
                                                              batch_size=250)
    print(x_train_split.shape, targets_train_split.shape, newstart)
```

Sample output:

```
(250, 1, 784) (250, 1) 250
(250, 1, 784) (250, 1) 500
(250, 1, 784) (250, 1) 750
(250, 1, 784) (250, 1) 1000
```

Comment: The error isn't in that line.  It's later when `idxs` is used as an index.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with your calculations.  OP's problem is with how he iterates and changes `x_train`.